# R Markdown: Always Run Certain Chunks, Skips Others

Tags: r, r-markdown

I need to run a repetitive code on multiple data sets.  I like to do this in R Markdown files because the drop-down headers make it easier to organize and navigate my code.  I rarely knit these files but instead run specific code chunks.

Some variables are the same across datasets: packages to load, a custom function, master csv file, etc.  I prefer to include these common elements in a separate code chunk at the top of the rmd file.  This facilitates simple modifications if needed, instead of needing to modify the same code within multiple chunks.

In my example below, when I run the Dataset 1 code chunk, I want it to first run the three chunks under the #Setup header and then run the Dataset 1 Chunk.  Dataset 2 Chunk is not run.

Similarly, when I run Dataset 2 Chunk, I want it to first run #Setup chunks followed by Dataset 2 Chunk.  Dataset 1 is not run.

```
# Setup

{r Setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=90),tidy=TRUE)
```

```
{r Packages, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
rm(list = ls()); invisible(gc()) #clear workspace and perform garbage collection to free up memory.

suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  { library(tidyverse)
    library(readxl)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(rtracklayer)
    library(trackViewer)
    library(ggplot2)
    }
)
```

```
# Specific Analyses

## Dataset 1
{r Dataset 1 Code, message = FALSE}
dataset1 <- read_excel("~/Desktop/Dataset1.xlsx, col_name=TRUE)
```

```
## Dataset 2 
{r Dataset 2 Code, message = FALSE}
dataset2 <- read_excel("~/Desktop/Dataset2.xlsx, col_name=TRUE)
```

Comment: I would urge you to reconsider your workflow, since RMarkdown simply really isn't made for this. Why not create modular code by splitting it into functions, and combining them as required? This is how reusable code *should* be structured, and lots of tools exist to assist this workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it by putting the setup code in a function and calling that function at the start of each analysis chunk.  If setup is slow, you could add a check to it so it only runs once per session (but then watch out if you change the setup data).

For example, replace your Setup and Packages chunk with this:

````
```{r SetupFunction, include=FALSE}
Setup <- function() {
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,
                        tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=90),
                        tidy=TRUE)
  #clear workspace and perform garbage collection to free up memory, but keep this function
  removals <- ls(globalenv())
  removals <- removals[removals != "Setup"]
  rm(list = removals, pos = globalenv())
  gc()      

  # Make sure packages are loaded
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(
    { library(tidyverse)
      library(readxl)
      library(ggplot2)
      library(rtracklayer)
      library(trackViewer)
      library(ggplot2)
    }
  )
 
  # Define a function.  Use `<<-` so it is available globally
  newfn <<- function(...) {
    print("this is newfn")
  }
}
```
````

Then at the start of each analysis chunk, just call `Setup()`.

The main weakness I see is that the `search()` list isn't being cleaned up, so if any of your analysis chunks attach variables or packages, it will keep those in other chunks as well.  You could fix this by saving the `search()` value and using `detach()` later to clean it up, but it's probably not needed.  You shouldn't ever use `attach()`, and to be consistent with the way you have this document set up, you should be putting all your `library()` calls in the `Setup()` function.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this?  I also have a function that is part of the setup.  I'm not sure how to nest a function within a function

Comment: I ran in to an issue.  My Setup has lines that read in csv files and define paths.  I added those lines to the Setup function, but it appears they they are not stored as variables.  When I run my subsequent code chunk, even though I run Setup() first, the variables are not found.

Comment: Did you use `<<-` for them, as I did for `newfn` in the example?

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize `<<-` was also used to retain variables.  It is working perfectly now.

Comment: `<<-` is very useful sometimes, so it's worth learning about.  Unlike `<-`, it doesn't assign locally.  It does the assignment in one of two places (which are sometimes the same):  if a variable matching the name exists in a parent environment of the current one, it assigns there.  If not, it assigns in the global environment.  This example used the global environment, which people usually advise against, since functions shouldn't have global side effects.  But your use case is an exception to that rule.